# Why shouldn't I use System.out.println() in android

Tags: android, logging

In the [Android Open Source Project's code style](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html), it states that we shouldn't use `System.out.println()` but I don't understand why. Can anyone explain? What should I use to trace my app's log?

Here's the line for reference:

> `System.out.println()` (or `printf()` for native code) should never be used. `System.out` and `System.err` get redirected to `/dev/null`, so your print statements will have no visible effects. However, all the string building that happens for these calls still gets executed.

Comment: Is this suggestion just for android source?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should use the [`android.util.Log`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class.

Here's a description of what the `Log` class does:

> API for sending log output.
>
> Generally, you should use the `Log.v()`, `Log.d()`, `Log.i()`, `Log.w()`, and `Log.e()` methods to write logs. You can then [view the logs in logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html).
>
> The order in terms of verbosity, from least to most is ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, VERBOSE. Verbose should never be compiled into an application except during development. Debug logs are compiled in but stripped at runtime. Error, warning and info logs are always kept.

These are the available methods of the `Log` class:

1. [`Log.d()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#d(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) - Send a [`DEBUG`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#DEBUG) log message.
2. [`Log.e()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#e(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) - Send an [`ERROR`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#ERROR) log message.
3. [`Log.i()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#i(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) - Send an [`INFO`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#INFO) log message.
4. [`Log.v()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#v(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) - Send a [`VERBOSE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#VERBOSE) log message.
5. [`Log.w()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#w(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) - Send a [`WARN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#WARN) log message.
6. [`Log.wtf()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#wtf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) - What a Terrible Failure: Report an exception that should never happen.

The methods above (with the exception of `Log.w` and `Log.wtf` which have 3 possible patterns of arguments) require the following arguments:

1. `String tag, String msg`:

   > `tag`: Used to identify the source of a log message. This value may be `null`.
   >
   > `msg`: The message you would like logged. This value may be `null`.
2. `String tag, String msg, Throwable tr` - Similar to the first pattern, but allows for an exception to be specified. This pattern should be used if you want to log an exception to the log output.
3. (For `Log.w` and `Log.wtf`) `String tag, Throwable tr` Similar to the third pattern, but does not allow for a message to be specified. Note that you can still pass a message but it should be in the second arrangement of arguments.

---

**EDIT**: Going straight to answer your question: `println()` of `System.out` and `System.err` will still be displayed in logcat but with limitations.

- You can't log `VERBOSE`, `ERROR`, or `DEBUG` using `System.out` or `System.err`.
- You can't define your own tag, it will display `System.err` or `System.out` with your text. For instance:

  - `System.out.println("Hello!")` is equivalent to `Log.i("System.out","Hello!")`
  - `System.err.println("Hello!")` is equivalent to `Log.w("System.err","Hello!")`

Comment: Log.wtf() obviously means "What a Terrible Failure" (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#wtf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29)

Answer (score 3):

`System.out.println("")` in android will not run well because there is no Terminal that the app is corrected to.

You would be better off using `Log.(d)(v)(e)(i)(w)`, because there is something actively monitoring LogCat.

`System.out.println()` will print to LogCat, but only after an additional set of System instuctions, making it not as efficient, however, as i said, it still works.

Answer (score 2):

if we want to trace the android project
we can do it using Log class
there is some methods like 
Log.e(TAG,MESSAGE)
Log.v(TAG,MESSAGE)
Log.w(TAG,MESSAGE)
Log.d(TAG,MESSAGE)
Log.i(TAG,MESSAGE)
its a static method of Utils package. put it line by line and u can watch it in the LogCat..
thats at enjoy with android

Answer (score 1):

From your own link:

> System.out.println() (or printf() for native code) should never be
>   used. System.out and System.err get redirected to /dev/null, so your
>   print statements will have no visible effects. However, all the string
>   building that happens for these calls still gets executed.

In addition, at the beginning of that page, it says:

> The rules below are not guidelines or recommendations, but strict
>   rules. Contributions to Android generally will not be accepted if they
>   do not adhere to these rules.

So **DON'T** do it!

Comment: How does this answer the "why" question?

Comment: @LarsH, well I think there's enough why there. I didn't add anything to what Android says to as why. It's pretty clear of why IMO. It has no visible effects but still takes processing time. If there's something I missed it'd be "how", in terms of what they should use instead for logging. When I have time I'll add that bit in.

Comment: Yeah, the first quote from the Android docs explains why, and that quote  is part of the original question. Your answer added only another quote that said "Don't!" but didn't add anything as to why. Hence my comment. You're right though that the OP does essentially ask "how" as well. Of course you can add something about that, but I think it's covered pretty well in other answers (i.e. use `Log.*()`).

Comment: And yet it does work? Perhaps a quiet addition to the framework while nobody was watching? I have a neophyte dev working for me who tossed a few System.out.println() calls in before I could stop him and it showed up in LogCat (Eclipse) just fine, no "tag" parameter required.

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard, Yeah it does. I actually saw a post yesterday that claimed they were not seeing anything from their `System.out.println` statements in an exception to which I said - is that a reliable way to debug Android... They said it works fine for them. It gets re-routed through `Log.i` as I understand it now, but probably no more reliable than what's above I guess...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in [Log utility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) that will print right out to the LogCat.

You can use `Log.e(String, String)` for errors which will appear in red. There is also `v`, `d`, `i`, and `w` for verbose, debug, info, and warning respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick to print the exception

**1.** Log.d("myapp", Log.getStackTraceString(new Exception()));

**or**

**2.** You can get longer stack traces by digging deeper. For example:

Log.getStackTraceString(e.getCause().getCause());

Answer (score 1):

Log is the best way to trace our android project
like following code...
it will help u...
just look in DDMS logCat that how exactly project is build...
requirement... android.utils.Log;  package is used..

```
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for(int i=0;i
    {

        Log.e("i = ",""+i);

        Log.v("i = ",""+i);

        Log.i("i = ",""+i);

        Log.w("i = ",""+i);

        Log.d("i = ",""+i);

    }

}
```

i hope it will help u