# Android - get XML from web

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to get XML datas from web and to show these datas into ListView. But something's going wrong when i run the project. Can you help me for this problem,please? Thank you.

XMLParser.java

```
public class XMLParser extends Activity {
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL uri=new URL("http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.connect();     

                    System.out.println("done");
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }).start();

//readfilethread.start();



        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        System.out.println("here");

       // HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        //HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        //xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;

}

public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
            // return DOM
        return doc;
}

public String getValue(Element item, String str) {      
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
    return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}

public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
  }
```

AndroidXMLParsingActivity.java

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {


// All static variables.. 

static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
// XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




        //  -> menuItems
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();




        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));


            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }


        // 2. Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.description, R.id.cost });
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        android.widget.ListView lv = getListView();

        // listening to single list item click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                startActivity(in);





            }
        });


    }
}
```

'

LOGCAT PART

```
08-25 08:34:10.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1700): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-25 08:34:10.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1700): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.uygulama/com.example.uygulama.AndroidXMLParsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

08-25 08:34:10.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1700): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.uygulama/com.example.uygulama.AndroidXMLParsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

08-25 08:34:10.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1700): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.uygulama/com.example.uygulama.AndroidXMLParsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

08-25 08:34:10.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

08-25 08:34:10.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

08-25 08:34:10.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

08-25 08:34:10.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

08-25 08:34:10.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

08-25 08:34:10.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

08-25 08:34:10.211: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)

....

08-25 08:34:10.341: I/System.out(1700): done
```

Comment: Whats the error ? Post your logcat trace

Comment: you are getting nullpointerexception indicate the line that causes the same and post the full stack trace.

Comment: I think you [should not use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393888/why-shouldnt-i-use-system-out-println-in-android/18393920#18393920) `System.out.println("done");`.

Comment: you should use a activity context change this `Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class)` to `Intent in = new Intent(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.this, SingleListItem.class)`

Comment: also `XMLParser` is an activity class. i don't see `onCreate` you are creating an instance of activity class? `XMLParser parser = new XMLParser()` you should start an activity using startActivity with intents. also i guess you need a `XMLParser` to be a utility class not an activity

Comment: you are retrieving the xml from web in a seperate thread, but your call is synchronous `String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); `, check for the xml before parsing the dom element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this codes ...

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NetActivity extends Activity {


    String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";   


    // Progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    ArrayList<String> title;
    ArrayList<String> description;
    ArrayList<String> id;
    ArrayList<String> cost;

    ItemAdapter adapter1;

    ListView list;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_net);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        title = new ArrayList<String>();
        description = new ArrayList<String>();  
        id = new ArrayList<String>();
        cost = new ArrayList<String>(); 


         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
             new XmlParsing(url).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new String[]{null});
         else
             new XmlParsing(url).execute(new String[]{null});

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class XmlParsing extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // variables passed in:
        String urls;
        //  constructor
        public XmlParsing(String urls) {
            this.urls = urls;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NetActivity.this, "Fetching Details..", "Please wait...", true);
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            URL url;
            try {

                url = new URL(urls);
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);       

                    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                    NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("name");
                    Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                    nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
                    title.add(""+ ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                    System.out.println("name : "+((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());


                    Element fstElmnt1 = (Element) node;
                    NodeList nameList1 = fstElmnt1.getElementsByTagName("id");
                    Element nameElement1 = (Element) nameList1.item(0);
                    nameList1 = nameElement1.getChildNodes();
                    description.add(""+ ((Node) nameList1.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                    System.out.println("id : "+ ((Node) nameList1.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                    Element fstElmnt2 = (Element) node;
                    NodeList nameList2 = fstElmnt2.getElementsByTagName("cost");
                    Element nameElement2 = (Element) nameList2.item(0);
                    nameList2 = nameElement2.getChildNodes();
                    id.add(""+ ((Node) nameList2.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                    System.out.println("cost : "+ ((Node) nameList2.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                    Element fstElmnt3 = (Element) node;
                    NodeList nameList3 = fstElmnt3.getElementsByTagName("description");
                    Element nameElement3 = (Element) nameList3.item(0);
                    nameList3 = nameElement3.getChildNodes();
                    cost.add(""+ ((Node) nameList3.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                    System.out.println("description : "+ ((Node) nameList3.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Now we have your JSONObject, play around with it.
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            adapter1 = new ItemAdapter(this);
            list.setAdapter(adapter1);

        }

    }


class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        final LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView title_text;
            public TextView des_text;
            public TextView id_text;
            public TextView cost_text;
        }

        public ItemAdapter(XmlParsing xmlParsing) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super();
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
        }

        //@Override
        public int getCount() {
            return title.size();
        }

        //@Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //@Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mainpage_listitem_activity, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.title_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
                holder.des_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.des_text);
                holder.id_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_text);
                holder.cost_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost_text);

                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            holder.title_text.setText(""+title.get(position));


            holder.des_text.setText(""+description.get(position));
            holder.id_text.setText(""+id.get(position));
            holder.cost_text.setText(""+cost.get(position));

        return view;
        }
    }
}
```