# How do you emulate an onDragListener in an emulator

Tags: android

I implemented an onDragListener like soo....

```
private final class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                System.out.println("STARTED");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                System.out.println("ENTERED");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                System.out.println("EXITED");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                System.out.println("DROP");
                myOnClickListener.onClick(v);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                System.out.println("ENDED");
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
```

and set it like so

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    boardLayout.getChildAt(i).setOnDragListener(myDragListener);
}
```

note **boardLayout** is a 8x8 **GridLayout**

When I click or drag or anything, nothing happens in the emulator, any ideas why?

When I make in an onClickListener everything works perfectly, so I have reason to believe that the emulator doesnt know that I am trying to drag maybe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register for `onTouchListener()` in each child.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {view.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                          ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                          DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                          view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                          view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                          return true;
                        } else {
                        return false;
                        }
                }
            });
}
```

Now this should work. I referenced from [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html)

You are printing the output. See output window for that.
However in android `Log.i(String, String)` method is recommend for debugging purpose. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah I know, that's the problem, nothing is being printed.

Comment: Please don't use System.out.println. Read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393888/why-shouldnt-i-use-system-out-println-in-android

Comment: I dont use it all the time, I use log, but I just needed to quickly test this