# Logging exceptions after publishing the application in Android

Tags: android, publish

In my application during development to know the errors I am using `system.out.println` to log the errors but when I publish the application how would I log the errors and how would I know what are the issues while using the application.

Comment: First of all read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393888/why-shouldnt-i-use-system-out-println-in-android .

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but my question is how to do it after publishing... as once `apk` is installed in users devices how would I know the errors?

Comment: You get the error report inside Your developer console. Click on the app You have published an select something similar to "crash&ANR" (don´t know how it is showed inside another country, I am from germany).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Crash Report**

- You get the report inside Your developer console but Google only log
  the exception to the server if the user clicks the "Report..."
  button, AFAIK.

**Get Crash and Exception Report**

- But if you want also get `exception report` as well as `crash report`,you may implement 
  (You may send exception/crash report to server programmatically)
  **Google Analytics for Android**
   This link may help you to get start [Google Analytics SDK v4 for Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Android UncaughtExceptionHandler.](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-uncaughtexceptionhandler.html) You can download the `source code` from

http://www.mediafire.com/download/pds2hlvnzceh2u8/AndroidMADQA_uncaughtException.zip