# Outputting database information through a list in another class - Eclipse Android SQLite

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I have built 3 classes, 1) **tableStudents** 2) **DB** 3) **MainActivity**

The code so far successfully creates a database and inserts into the database given set coded test data. However I cannot figure out how to print this information just to show that it indeed has successfully entered it.

- I am on a University computer therefore I cannot access the database file
- Without going through the file, I have tried outputting the list using the method I have wrote to get the data, but I am unsure how to physically output it as text.

Fullcode as follows:

**tableStudents.java**

```
public class tableStudents {
     public String name, gender, password, course, modules;
        public int age;
    //Constructor
    public tableStudents()
    {

    }

     //constructor
    public tableStudents(String name, String gender, int age, String password, String course, String modules)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;      
        this.course = course;
        this.modules = modules;
    }


    public static abstract class tableColumns implements BaseColumns
    {
        public static final String Student_ID= "Student_ID";
        public static final String Student_Name= "Student_Name";
        public static final String Student_Password = "Student_Password";
        public static final String Student_Gender = "gender";
        public static final String Student_Age = "age";
        public static final String Student_Course = "course";
        public static final String Modules = "modules";
        public static final String Database = "databasename";
        public static final String Table = "tablename";
    }


}
```

**DB.java**

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int db_version = 1;  
    public static final String Table = "Students";  
    public static final String Student_ID = "Student_ID";
    public static final String Student_Name = "Student_Name";
    public static final String Student_Password = "Student_Password";
    public static final String Student_Gender = "gender";
    public static final String Student_Age = "age";
    public static final String Student_Course = "course";
    public static final String Modules = "modules";
    public DB(Context context) {
        super(context, tableColumns.Database, null, db_version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Create Table
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Table + "(" + 
                Student_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                Student_Name + " TEXT, " +
                Student_Password + " TEXT, " +
                Student_Gender + " TEXT, " +
                Student_Age + " INTEGER, " +
                Student_Course + " TEXT, " +
                Modules + " TEXT)");
        Log.d("DB", "DB Created");      
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public List<tableStudents> getData() {
        List<tableStudents> studentList = new ArrayList<tableStudents>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Table;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                tableStudents student = new tableStudents();
                student.name = cursor.getString(0);
                student.password = cursor.getString(1);
                student.gender = cursor.getString(2);
                student.age = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3));          
                student.course = cursor.getString(4);
                student.modules = cursor.getString(5);
                studentList.add(student);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return contact list
        return studentList;
    }


    public boolean insertStudent(String name, String gender, int age, String password, String course, String modules) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Student_Name, name);
        contentValues.put(Student_Password, password);
        contentValues.put(Student_Gender, gender);
        contentValues.put(Student_Age, age);        
        contentValues.put(Student_Course, course);
        contentValues.put(Modules, modules);
        Log.d("DB", "Inserted Successfully");
        return true;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Intent appIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        DB db = new DB(this);
        db.insertStudent("T", "T", 5, "T", "T", "T");
        List<tableStudents> outputList = db.getData();     
    }

    public void goHomepage(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Homepage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void goAccount(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyAccount.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do a `SELECT` to retrieve your data and compare to the original?

Comment: my getData method in DB.java has that mate

Comment: Then what is the part you are missing? Are you required to provide an output to someone else to prove that your code is working? If so, just [`Log`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18394023/2055998) your data.

Comment: I just want to see the inserted information and prove it's been inserted into a database for my own recognition, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a `List`, so you could display the corresponding data using a `ListView`.  If you simply want to see the data returned from getData, you could loop through the array and `Log` it to your logcat output.

```
for (tableStudents student: outputList) {
    // Log your results.
    Log.d("result_list", student.toString())
}
```

If you want to display this information in your app, you would use a `ListView`.
Android provides a basic interface for arbitrary data and the listview, which you can extend and customize if you feel the need to, called `BaseAdapter`.  They also provide concrete implementations of the `BaseAdapter` for you to use without much work.

One such implementation is the `ArrayAdapter` class. ([See here)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) This class is described as follows:

> A concrete BaseAdapter that is backed by an array of arbitrary objects. By default this class expects that the provided resource id references a single TextView. If you want to use a more complex layout, use the constructors that also takes a field id. That field id should reference a TextView in the larger layout resource.
>
> However the TextView is referenced, it will be filled with the toString() of each object in the array. You can add lists or arrays of custom objects. Override the toString() method of your objects to determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list.

Therefore, you can create a `ListView` in your activity's layout file, give it an id, and create an adapter to power that `ListView`. For example:

Start by creating the list view in your activity xml file.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/my_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Once that is defined, you should override the `tableStudents.toString()` method and implement a user friendly version that displays pertinent fields as a string.

**tableStudents.java** (Generally, you should avoid doing this, and instead, extend the `ArrayAdapter`, then override `getView()` and display the object's properties there)

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    out.append("Student: ")
    out.append(this.name);
    // etc.
    return out.toString();
}
```

Now in your activity after you call `getData()`, reference the `ListView` and create the `ArrayAdapter`:

**MainActivity.java**

```
List<tableStudents> outputList = db.getData();

// Reference the list view.
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);

// Create the adapter.
ArrayAdapter listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(
        this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        android.R.id.text1,
        outputList
);

// Then set the adapter for the list view.
listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
```

Your database results should be displayed in a nice scroll-able list in your app.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thankyou for your very imformative answer! I'll be able to test it out in a few hours time, so bear with me. Thanks again.