# string & system.out.println and other functions doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I just started coding in android studio, but it doesn't even recognize string or system.out.println as a defined function.
My android studio version is 1.5 and java 1.8

[image: reference image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html read this to know how to log info and error in android

Comment: Try to use autocompletion.

Comment: Please provide your real code and not an image of your code. For example, I cannot see it.

Comment: Please, can you provide your code directly in the post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Classnames starts with a capital letter on `Java`

```
System.out.println();
```

In this case you can also use the Logcat console,

```
Log.v(TAG, your_value_var);
```

**I give you anothers comments and advices.**

**First** of all I think you should download a `Java language` paper from the beginning, there you would see and you could clarify all these doubts and you could solve all the language problems.

**Secondly** I would advise you to download the latest version of Android Studio, the one you are using is a bit old, maybe with bugs and others, [Android Studio 3](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), made many changes for our benefit.

**And finally** I advise you here Stackoverflow when you ask a question is because we have tried to solve the problem in many ways by other ways and we have tried many times, things like these are not wonder here, but we see that you are very new, and that's how we all started.

***Welcome to the Community.***

*I hope it helps you improve.*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18373661)

Comment: I edited my answer, you are right. Thanks.

Comment: found it really helpful ,also thanks for inspiration .

Answer (score 0):

Class names are started in a capitalized letter.

So:

String and System.out.println works instead of string and system

Answer (score 0):

On Java, **Classnames starts with a capital letter** (in your case `System`).

Also, on Android, use [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class is better than use System.out.println() ([Why shouldn't I use System.out.println() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393888/why-shouldnt-i-use-system-out-println-in-android)).