# I'm trying to pass string from fragment to activity, and then that activity to fragment. I am getting null when it is going from fragment to activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Issue is as title says. The sending fragment is going to send a url as a string to the main activity when an item in the navigation drawer is selected

Code for Sending Frag:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    String newurl = webview.getUrl();
    System.out.println(newurl);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("newurl", newurl);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

Code for Receiving Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    //creating fragment object
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String newurl = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("newurl");
    System.out.println(newurl);
    //initializing the fragment object which is selected
    if (itemId == R.id.nav_assignments) {
        Fragment fragment1 =  new HomeFragment();
        ((HomeFragment) fragment1).setName(newurl);
        displaySelectedFragment(fragment1);

    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_grades) {
            fragment = new GalleryFragment();
            displaySelectedFragment(fragment);

    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_people) {
            fragment = new SlideshowFragment();
            displaySelectedFragment(fragment);

    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_syllabus) {
            fragment = new ToolsFragment();
            displaySelectedFragment(fragment);

    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_discussions) {
            fragment = new ShareFragment();
            displaySelectedFragment(fragment);

    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_settings) {
            fragment = new SendFragment();
            displaySelectedFragment(fragment);
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

I've been using System.out.println to debug when the url becomes null, and that piece of code in the sending fragment does not initialize. As soon as I press the item in the nav drawer, the app crashes. How do I fix this? (By the way some of the extra code is because I'm sending the data from the sending frag to the main activity and then to another frag)

Comment: Hi Tanay, welcome to StackOverflow! For a start, please consider using one of the available [`android.util.Log`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log)-related methods to log messages instead of `System.out.println`. See this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393888/why-shouldnt-i-use-system-out-println-in-android

Comment: @Edric I did as you said (using Log.d) and it has the same behavior. For some reason I think the @ Override is not being called in the sending fragment because there is no message in the debug log right before the intent is started.