# getStringExtra() function returns Intent { (has extras) }

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm passing a string from activity A to activity B and using the passed string in activity B.
Code for passing data to B from A (`data` **is a string**. But to remove any doubt, I'm also using `toString()`):

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this,Class.forName("com.example.mylibrary.BActivity"));
   intent.putExtra("user",data.toString());
   startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

Code for getting passed data in activity B:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

        String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
        System.out.println(text);
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textView.setText(text);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    }
```

**Error:**
But the value of string `text` is `Intent { (has extras) }`. This is what is printed on console and on app screen for activity B as `text` is put in `textView4`. The expected value of `text` should be a string that user entered in last activity. Can anyone tell me why the `getIntent().getStringExtra("user");` does not return the actual string passed but `Intent { (has extras) }`?[`App screen`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEcbT.png)

**Console output for System.out.println(text)**

```
V/FA: onActivityCreated
I/System.out: Intent { (has extras) }
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 7152294
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xef57f8e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe43eef50)
```

Comment: Pass hardcoded value like Intent intent = new Intent(this, BActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("user", "User Value");
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: And Comment this 2 lines Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

Comment: intent.putExtra("user",data.toString());
What type is data? I think it is of type Intent?

Comment: Putting hard coded value made me realise it is actually working fine. I have two 'data' variables and I assumed the other one to be this 'data'. Thanks for the advise @Pavya and sorry for the silly question.

Comment: @Shrikant Yes, the ```data``` variable which I was using was of type Intent. I was writing the code in completely different function.

Comment: you can use shared preferences for simple and better results

Comment: @Akanksha_p Its ok and keep trying

Comment: Obviously the variable `data` is either an `Intent` (not a `String`), or it contains the text "Intent {has extras}". Please add debug logging and output the value of `data` BEFORE you put it in the `Intent1 extras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replicated the same scenario mentioned with the Activity Classes and Layout XMLs mentioned:

`activity_a.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_navigate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/navigate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`AActivity.java`

```
public class AActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private View.OnClickListener navigateClickListener = view ->
        navigateToSecondActivity();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
        initializeViews();
    }

    private void initializeViews() {      
        findViewById(R.id.button_navigate)
            .setOnClickListener(navigateClickListener);
    }

    private void navigateToSecondActivity() {
        String data = "Some Data"; // Here I'm setting a String as the data to be sent.
        Intent intent = new Intent(AActivity.this, BActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("user", data.toString());
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

}
```

`activity_b.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`BActivity.java`

```
public class BActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
        String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
        System.out.println(text);
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textView.setText(text);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    }

}
```

When I build the APK, deployed APK on an Emulator, the code ran just fine.

[image: AActivity]

[image: BActivity]

What I suspect is that the `data` on your code might have been set value something like this:

```
data = someIntent.toString();
```

Reasoning for my suspicion being the value you are getting as `Intent { (has extras) }`

So, I suggest to check throughout how the `data` is changed by printing the value on each change.

Also, print the value of `data` just before calling the method `startActivityForResult()` on `AActivity` to make sure it was the value you intended to send to `BActivity`.

Some notes though:

- In `AActivity.java`, it is useless to use `data.toString()`, since `data` is itself a `String`, and calling `data.toString()` returns the same value, which makes calling it redundant.
- For Printing Any Value in the Console/Logcat, use `android.util.Log` instead of `System.out.println()`. [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18394023/5367936)!
- Using `Class.forName("com.example.mylibrary.BActivity")` is same as `BActivity.class`, and the latter is more convinient.