# Android Studio logcat message "All logs entries are hidden by the filter"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, filter, logcat

I am using Android studio giraffe version, and when I clicked on clear logcat, then this message is appearing "All logs entries are hidden by the filter". How can I get rid of this message and use filter as I want to use it. Error is shown in screenshot, thanks

[logcat message as I type in filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suqF2.png)

I override the activity life cycle methods and I wanted to observe its behavior. I was printing messages in print() method, and it was working fine, but when I clicked on clear logs, then I am getting this message "All logs entries are hidden by the filter". Please guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `System.out` query from search field.. leave it empty. also you may use "Restart Logcat" button, visible on your screen on left side, green rounded arrow

Answer (score 0):

First of all in Android we use the `android.util.Log` class for log statements. More on this topic in this post: [Why shouldn't I use System.out.println() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18394023/9641046).

Back to your observed behavior.
As you already did, you can filter the received logs. A common one is `package:mine` or/and `tag:<your tag you wrote in the android.util.Log statement>`. With the filtering you have basically two sets of logs: the filtered one (the one you see) and the unfiltered.
If you decide to clear the Logcat (with the filter still in place), you just clear the filtered logs. The filtered out logs (the one you don't see) are not cleared. That's what the message `All log entries are hidden by the filter` is telling you.

To resolve this "issue" you can either

- clear the logcat again
- clear the filter